# OpenCL write to buffer choices

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two ways to create a buffer object in opencl: clCreateBuffer vs. clCreateBuffer + clEnqueueWriteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832963/two-ways-to-create-a-buffer-object-in-opencl-clcreatebuffer-vs-clcreatebuffer)

What is the difference between copying data to the device immediately upon buffer creation vs. later?
ie.

```
cl_mem memObj = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR
, size, dataPtr, NULL);
```

or

```
cl_mem memObj = clCreateBuffer( context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY , size, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer( commandQueue, memObj, CL_TRUE, 0, size, dataPtr, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I'm brand new to OpenCL, so I'm just trying to figure things out ie. which method is best to use.

Thanks!

Comment: oops, yes this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the create/enqueue thing (in general, not just in opencl) is that once you create a buffer, you can write to it later after you compute what you want to write, and write an arbitrary number of times. There's no functional difference between initializing a buffer with data in it and making a buffer and then adding the data. Futhermore, any performace difference should be optimized away by your compiler.